# brain type internal not showing unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I have trained a model with Python(PPO). I got the byte file for brain but when I try to select brain type, it doesn't show any `Internal` option. I'm using `ML-AgentsNoPlugin.unitypackage` for this project. Please let me know what's wrong

[image: ml-agent brain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the same issue.

The solution is:

1. put ENABLE_TENSORFLOW in Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Scripting Define Symbols (type it, click return and tab...in this way it keeps it after restart)
2. set Scripting Runtime Version to Experimental (.Net 4.6 Equivalent)

Restart Unity and it should work.